# Last vs most recently

Tags: meaning

> When did you eat in this restaurant the last?
>
> When did you eat in this reasturant most recently?

Are there any difference between two sentence in meaning ? Especially I am not sure whether first one is correct or not . When I say one of these sentence The one who I spoke to understand the same ? And should I use “the” before “last”?

Comment: I would rewrite the first question to 'When did you last eat in this restaurant?' And the second change it into: 'Have you been here recently?' For me, the second questions sounds more like a police investigation question than an informal conversation.

Comment: Why we don’t use “last”  at the end of the sentence? Or would it be wrong if I use at the end?

Comment: You can put it at the end, the same way I can write a grammatically correct sentence saying: 'when in this restaurant did you last eat', but the 'feeling' of the whole thing is off..

Comment: Thank you so much . Last question actually I want to ask if I use it before “eat”.

Comment: @Sara: I'm not sure about 'when in this restaurant did you last eat'. To me, it sounds like the prepositional phrase can be used after "when" only if it denoted a point in time; i.e. "When in this year did you last eat here?".

Answer (score 2):

"Most recently" doesn't sound quite right here; it's a little too formal.

You wouldn't use "the" before "last". So:

> When did you eat in this restaurant last?

Though, for me, it would be more idiomatic to say:

> When did you last eat in this restaurant?

And going a little further, as the listener is likely to know which restaurant you mean by "this restaurant", you could simply say:

> When did you last eat here?

Answer (score 0):

“When did you last eat” is fine.  But it is unnatural to with qualifiers like “in this restaurant”. I am not sure there is a good rule for you here, sadly.